# Inject service into an isolated ts file's function, outside of module in Nest Js v10

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a module named by `User`, an isolated `utils.ts` under `utils folder`. The `utils.ts` is not part of any module. I have a function inside the `utils.ts`. I want to inject the `user.service.ts` inside the **function** that is present inside the `utils.ts`.
After my code configurations I'm facing the following error

> Error: Nest could not find UserService element (this provider does not exist in the current context)

**CODE**

**main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.enableCors();

  app.get(UserService, { strict: false });

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

**The Function inside the isolated `utils.ts` file**

```
export async function convertDtoToClass(
  dto:
    | CreateUserRequest
    | UpdateUserDto
    | CreateCustomerRequest
    | UpdateCustomerDto,
  requiredResultClass: any,
  moduleRef?: ModuleRef,
): Promise<User | Customer> {
 //other code

  if (res && requiredResultClass.name === 'CreateCustomerRequest') {
    console.log(requiredResultClass.name);

    return await convertCustomerDto(dto as CreateCustomerRequest, moduleRef);
  }
}


async function convertCustomerDto(
  dto: CreateCustomerRequest | UpdateCustomerDto,
  moduleRef: ModuleRef,
): Promise<Customer> {
  const userService = moduleRef.get<UserService>(UserService);
//other code
}
```

**customer.conroller.ts, here the functions from `utils.ts`, are called**

```
export class CustomerController {
  constructor(
    private readonly customerService: CustomerService,
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) {}

@Post()
  async create(
    @Body() createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerRequest,
  ): Promise<any> {

    let customer: Customer = (await convertDtoToClass(
      createCustomerDto,
      CreateCustomerRequest,
      this.moduleRef,
    )) as Customer;

    console.log(customer);
    return await this.customerService.create(customer);
  }
}
```

**user.module.ts**

```
  @Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: UserSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    CustomerModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**NOTE:I SAW SOMEWHERE THAT I HAVE TO PROVIDE `UserService` TO `AppModule's`, `providers:[]`  ,IF I PROVIDE `UserService` in the `providers:[AppService,UserService]` I FACE FOLLOWING ERROR**

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, CACHE_MANAGER). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

**I used  `useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });` as well**

Answer (score 0):

**I've solved the issue.It is a very simple solution at the end**

Just pass the **desired service** as a parameter to the function and it will work.NO need to customize `main.ts`, also no need to pass the `moduleRef`.NO other exports or imports, **JUST PASS THE SERVICE AS A PARAMETER.**

**Code**

**In controller.ts**

```
export class CustomerController {
  constructor(
    private readonly customerService: CustomerService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  async create(
    @Body() createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerRequest,
  ): Promise<any> {
    let customer: Customer = (await convertDtoToClass(
      createCustomerDto,
      CreateCustomerRequest,
      this.userService,
    )) as Customer;

    console.log(customer);
    return await this.customerService.create(customer);
  }
```

**In isolated `utils.ts`**

```
export async function convertDtoToClass(
  dto:
    | CreateUserRequest
    | UpdateUserDto
    | CreateCustomerRequest
    | UpdateCustomerDto,
  requiredResultClass: any,
  userService?: UserService,
): Promise<User | Customer> {
 
  if (res && requiredResultClass.name === 'CreateCustomerRequest') {
    console.log(requiredResultClass.name);

    return await convertCustomerDto(dto as CreateCustomerRequest, userService);
  }
}


export async function convertCustomerDto(
  dto: CreateCustomerRequest | UpdateCustomerDto,
  userService: UserService,
): Promise<Customer> {
//use the userService however you desire
}
```